# How do I set a local variable declared in a nested method to be within the parent method's scope?

Tags: ruby, scope

I am having problems with Ruby's scoping.

I have method 'foobar' which has two methods inside it. I want each of 'foobar's methods to initialize a variable that can be used by 'foobar'.

Below is my Error & Code:

> undefined local variable or method `old_var'

```
def initialize
    @sandbox = #working api call
end

def foobar

        @sandbox.function() do |resp|
             old_var = resp.var.to_f
        end

        sleep(10)

        @sandbox.function() do |resp|
             new_var = resp.var.to_f
        end

        new_var + old_var;

    end
```

Comment: Ruby doesn't have nested methods, nor do I see anything in your code that could be called "nested methods". It is possible to nest a method definition inside a method body, but that does not create a nested method. And I don't see a method definition nested in a method body in your code either. Can you clarify your question, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the result of the proc to `old_var` so that it’s declared on the same scope where used.

```
old_var = 
  @sandbox.function() do |resp|
    resp.var.to_f
  end
```

The same for `new_var`:

```
new_var = 
  @sandbox.function() do |resp|
    resp.var.to_f
  end
```

---

> How do I set a local variable declared in a nested method to be within the parent method's scope?

Answering the question in the title: that is impossible.

---

If you need to perform some actions before returning a value from a nested block, use `break`:

```
value =
  @sandbox.function() do |resp|
    foo = 42
    # do something else
    break foo
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

Variables defined inside a block are scoped to the block. Define your variables outside the block, and then you can modify them inside the block. This will allow you to access them after the block completes.

```
def initialize
    @sandbox = #working api call
end

def foobar
    # defining these two variables so you can set them
    # inside the block later
    old_var = nil
    new_var = nil

    @sandbox.function() do |resp|
         old_var = resp.var.to_f
    end

    sleep(10)

    @sandbox.function() do |resp|
         new_var = resp.var.to_f
    end

    new_var + old_var;
end
```

Comment: This is a _very_ bad practice and it should be avoided. Many languages directly restrict this mess with scopes.

Comment: Sometimes it’s not your method, so you can’t change what the defined method returns. You don’t know what `@sandbox.function()` is. Also, do you have a citation on how Ruby says it’s bad practice? Ruby would prohibit it if they cared about scopes that much. @AlekseiMatiushkin

Comment: If it’s not your method, use `break` as shown in the last para of my answer. No, I don’t have a citation on hand, but Ruby does not prohibit anything; it does not mean we should use monkeypatching, scope leaking and other _bad design decisions_ here and there. (`break` might bypass the code after `yield` in the `function` though.)

Comment: Using break in a block that isn’t yours is not safe though. Because as you said, it bypasses anything after the yield in that function. I would say using break to return something from a block like that is arguably worse because you don’t know (and shouldn’t know) the inner workings of that other method. Ruby limits scopes the way it does to prevent leaking the variable unintentionally. But intentionally pulling variables out of a block is permitted. If it’s your method, it should return what you expect (old_val/new_val), if it’s not then I think my way is much safer.

Comment: I agree with here, sometimes you're stuck with someone else's interface and have to use a bit of trickery to make it go.